# Join to pull the minimum date in Table Y that is greater than a date in Table X per item ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I found lots of answers to similar issues, but not an answer to this exact issue. I feel like this should be easy, but it's making my brain hurt.

The pattern is I have a table of rentals and a table of returns. Each item can be rented and returned multiple times. Lucky for me, those are stored in different tables.

Table X (Rentals)

```
ID    Type   Date Rented
0001  A       2017-02-01
0001  A       2017-07-01
0001  A       2017-09-01
0002  B       2017-01-01
0002  B       2017-05-01
```

Table Y (Returns)

```
ID    Date Returned
0001  2017-05-01
0001  2017-08-01
0002  2017-04-01
```

I want to end up with:

```
ID    Type    Date Rented    Date Returned
0001  A       2017-02-01     2017-05-01
0001  A       2017-07-01     2017-08-01
0001  A       2017-09-01     NA
0002  B       2017-01-01     2017-04-01
0002  B       2017-05-01     NA
```

So I am looking, for each ID and Rental Date, the MINIMUM value in the Return Table that is greater than that rental date.

I'll be working with the output in R, so if there is an easier way to do this in R / dplyr rather than SQL, I'm all ears...

Comment: I think you need to provide a more representative example, with more IDs. I think that if both datasets are ordered in terms of dates you can just join using the row number (for each specific ID).

Comment: Edited to add a second id, thanks.

Comment: Not sure why your second dataset has "rented" in the column name when it represents returns :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
ID    Type   DateRented
0001  A       2017-02-01
0001  A       2017-07-01
0001  A       2017-09-01
0002  B       2017-01-01
0002  B       2017-05-01
", header=T)

df2 = read.table(text = "
ID    DateRented
0001  2017-05-01
0001  2017-08-01
0002  2017-04-01
", header=T)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# update to a date format and order by ID and date
# (not needed if you have already a date format and ascending order)
df1 = df1 %>% mutate(DateRented = ydm(DateRented)) %>% arrange(ID, DateRented)
df2 = df2 %>% mutate(DateRented = ydm(DateRented)) %>% arrange(ID, DateRented)

# add row ids for each ID to your datasets
df1 = df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% ungroup()
df2 = df2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% ungroup()

# join datasets and remove row id column
left_join(df1, df2, by=c("ID","row_id")) %>% select(-row_id)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#    ID Type   DateRented.x DateRented.y
#   <int> <fctr> <date>       <date>     
# 1     1 A      2017-02-01   2017-05-01  
# 2     1 A      2017-07-01   2017-08-01  
# 3     1 A      2017-09-01   NA          
# 4     2 B      2017-01-01   2017-04-01  
# 5     2 B      2017-05-01   NA
```

Comment: Note: This breaks if there is a return for an item that happens before the rental. Looks like the two tables had extract criteria based on the same cutoff date, so there are some items with a rental date prior to the cutoff date, and that return is after the cutoff. The row #s don't align in those cases.

Comment: Best way to fix it is to post an example of a case like this and specify how you want it to be treated.

Answer (score 2):

Merge, set return date to NA if it is earlier than rent date, then group by and get minimum date for return.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(x, y, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(DateReturned = if_else(DateReturned < DateRented, as.Date(NA), DateReturned)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Type, DateRented) %>% 
  summarise(DateReturnedMin = min(DateReturned, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()
  
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#      ID  Type DateRented DateReturnedMin
#   <int> <chr>     <date>          <date>
# 1     1     A 2017-02-01      2017-05-01
# 2     1     A 2017-07-01      2017-08-01
# 3     1     A 2017-09-01              NA
# 4     2     B 2017-01-01      2017-04-01
# 5     2     B 2017-05-01              NA
```

---

Or if we prefer to use SQL, then use *sqldf* package, same logic as above:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select ID, Type, DateRented__Date, min(DateReturned__Date) as DateReturnedMin__Date
       from (
             select x.ID, Type, DateRented as DateRented__Date,
                   (case when (DateReturned < DateRented)         
                         then NULL 
                         else DateReturned
                    end) as DateReturned__Date
             from x, y
             where x.ID = y.ID) a
       group by ID, Type, DateRented__Date",
      method = "name__class")

# ID   Type DateRented DateReturnedMin
# 1  1    A 2017-02-01      2017-05-01
# 2  1    A 2017-07-01      2017-08-01
# 3  1    A 2017-09-01            <NA>
# 4  2    B 2017-01-01      2017-04-01
# 5  2    B 2017-05-01            <NA>
```

---

### data

```
x <- read.table(text = "
ID    Type   DateRented
0001  A       2017-02-01
0001  A       2017-07-01
0001  A       2017-09-01
0002  B       2017-01-01
0002  B       2017-05-01", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

y <- read.table(text = "
ID    DateReturned
0001  2017-05-01
0001  2017-08-01
0002  2017-04-01", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# convert to date class
x$DateRented <- as.Date(x$DateRented, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
y$DateReturned <- as.Date(y$DateReturned, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: I really like the SQL approach. When I don't already have the data in two data frames, this seems like the best way to pull it straight from the database. In this case, I didn't have that opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

We could use a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(X)[Y, DateReturned := DateReturned,on =.(ID, DateRented< DateReturned), mult = "last"]
X
#   ID Type DateRented DateReturned
#1:  1    A 2017-02-01   2017-05-01
#2:  1    A 2017-07-01   2017-08-01
#3:  1    A 2017-09-01         <NA>
#4:  2    B 2017-01-01   2017-04-01
#5:  2    B 2017-05-01         <NA>
```